# Best way to deprecate a homebrew tap to transition to another tap?

Tags: homebrew

Here is my situation :
I have created a homebrew `tap` to host some tools, let's call it `me/poor-name`.
Now I would like to transition to a better named tap called `me/tools` for various reasons.

Is there a way to print some kind of deprecation warning for a while when my users install tools from `me/poor-name`, so that they progressively use `me/tools` as a tap ?

Or is there a better way to handle the transition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't support renaming taps, but [it does allow migrating formulae from one tap to another](https://docs.brew.sh/Migrating-A-Formula-To-A-Tap).

> 1. Create a pull request to the new tap adding the formula file as-is from the original tap. Fix any test failures that may occur due to the stricter requirements for new formulae than existing formula (e.g. `brew audit --strict` must pass for that formula).
> 2. Create a pull request to the original tap deleting the formula file and add it to `tap_migrations.json` with a commit message like `gv: migrate to homebrew/core`.
> 3. Put a link for each pull request in the other pull request so the maintainers can merge them both at once.

For example, here is the `tap_migrations.json` file for `brewsci/science`: https://github.com/brewsci/homebrew-science/blob/master/tap_migrations.json

Also, this feature should work the same with casks. (It's just not documented.)